# gedit highlight misspelled words for every document by default

Tags: gedit, spell-checking

Every time I open documents and for every new documents I have to re-enable the [spell-checker in gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-spellcheck.html.en).

How can I toggle it to always be on for every document?

Comment: Have you found a solution about that?

Comment: did you try `~/.config/enchant` ?

Answer (score 3):

No it can not be set as default.

That does not rule out that someone who knows how to decompile, reprogram and recompile the spell checker plugin for gedit can't make a setting for it, it is open source.

@NIMISHAN:  Enchant is a dictionary, and is not responsible for spell checking, nor part of any program.  Programs can use it.  Even the spell checker in gedit is not part of gedit, just a plugin, plugged into gedit.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in gedit as of 3.38.2:

Got to Preferences -> Plugins -> Spellchecker -> Preferences and tick "Highlight Missepelled words".

Credit to [sweetfinger](https://askubuntu.com/users/998551/sweetfinger) for his previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650893/gedit-highlight-misspelled-words-enabled-by-default/860447?newreg=0fce7106314d48d397e4b758c2702a95).