# Gedit "Highlight Misspelled Words" enabled by default

Tags: 14.04, gedit, gtk3, spell-checking

I'm using gedit 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the Spell checker enabled. At the moment, I have to enable the "Highlight Misspelled Words" option every time I open a file, even if it is the same file. I would like to have the "Highlight Misspelled Words" option enabled by default when I open gedit.

I searched for an answer and I only found [this 2007 forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=990364) that links to a bug that offers a command that doesn't work in my version of Ubuntu/gedit as a solution.

Is it possible to have the "Highlight Misspelled Words" option enabled by default in this version of Ubuntu/gedit?

It would also be nice to have the "Set Language…" option enabled by default as well without having to change the language of my entire system.

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [@jozxyqk](https://askubuntu.com/users/196639/jozxyqk) for providing a more recent link:
[gedit highlight misspelled words for every document by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541532/gedit-highlight-misspelled-words-for-every-document-by-default)

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-spellcheck.html.en claims it should be enabled all the time if you enabled. I would still consider it a bug if it does not stay enabled.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry guys, I wasn't using the right words. I wrote "spell checker" when what I meant was the "Highlight Misspelled Words" option. Please check out my edited question. Thanks in advance and sorry.

Comment: [The same question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/541532/gedit-highlight-misspelled-words-for-every-document-by-default), still no answer yet.

Comment: @jozxyqk Thank you for providing a more recent link :-) I'm starting to think it's not possible to do this, and the plugin authors are not active... We will have to code something ourselves. I'd do it if I knew how to make gedit plugins (or update the existing ones). Whoever codes this functionality into the Spell Checker will be my hero until the Sun dies.

Comment: I had a shot at plugins but it seems some updates to the API are not reflected by the docs/tutorials. Might be a few years until the gedit3 changes settle and its worth trying :(

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get 'Highlight Misspellt Words' enabled by default. Go to:

Options -> Preferences -> Plugins

Right-click on the 'Spell Checker' plugin and select 'Preferences'. You will be presented with a single optoin to have highlighting of misspelt words the default for new documents.

Answer (score 0):

No it can not be set as default.

That does not rule out that someone who knows how to decompile, reprogram and recompile the spell checker plugin for gedit can't make a setting for it, it is open source after all.  If it is indeed abandoned, then it is even more so free game.  Just give credit where due.  I would love to have this option, and setting a different language as default too.

Comment: It is possible nowadays. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1175926/62141

Answer (score -1):

i think add spell checker plugin in gedit
1st of all
open gedit.then Click preferences inside edit button.then click plugin button, and then add spell checker plugin

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't using the right words. I wrote "spell checker" when what I meant was the "Highlight Misspelled Words" option. Please check out my edited question. Thanks in advance and sorry.